# ExtJS/JavaScript - show image when using replace() function

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I'm not sure exactly how much this question has something to do with ExtJS and how much with pure JavaScript. Anyways I have a string with comma separated value. I need to use for the `GUI` so I try to make it as user-friendly as I can. I made most of the things I wanted but one thing I can't accomplish yet. I want to replace all commas in the string with a proper image, which I think will fit very well on what I'm doing but for now - I try with no success.

For those familiar with ExtJS - I'm doing this for each cell in a certain column of a grid with a render function. But I think that maybe the problem must be solved with a pure JavaScript function. Here is what I have by now:

```
_cusomizeString: function(dates) {
        if (dates != null)
        {
            var date = dates.replace(/,/g,"|");
            var www = date.split('|');
            var xxx = www.length;
            for (var i = 2; i < xxx; i+=3)
                {
                    www[i] = www[i] + '<br />';
                }
            var ggg = www.toString();
            var hhh = ggg.replace(/,/g,'<img src =" ' + D:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\img.png + ' "/>');
            return hhh;

        }
        return dates;
    }
```

I tried a few variations, now I don't get error but don't see an image either.

Thanks

Leron

P.S

With this change in the function:

```
var finalString = tempString.replace(/,/g,'<img src ="http://www.finishingtouch.co.uk/assets/images/common/calendar_icon.png"/>');
```

I am able to visualize this:

[image: How my images look]

The main problem now is how to add the image before the first element, because now it's missing (Noticeable especially when there's only one date) and how I can make it work with local files for now? I've tried using this in my `replace` function:

```
'<img src ="file:///D:\\symapac\\src\\public\\img\\icons\\draft.png"/>'
```

But the console log returns this and I dont see no image:

```
07-06-2012<img src ="file:///D:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\img.png"/>16-06-2012
```

Ok, I have almost final solution. Here is how it looks like:

[image: After the final adjustments]

Here is my final function:

```
_checkDates: function(dates) {
        if (dates != null)
        {
            var date = dates.replace(/,/g,"|");
            var arrayOfDates = date.split('|');
            var stringLength = arrayOfDates.length;
            for (var i = 2; i < stringLength; i+=3)
                {
                    arrayOfDates[i] = arrayOfDates[i] + '<br />';
                }
            var tempString = arrayOfDates.toString();
            var finalString = tempString.replace(/,/g," ,");
                finalString = finalString.replace(/,/g,"<img src="+ "'" + pathToImage + "'" +"/>");
            var imgSrc = "<img src="+ "'" + pathToImage + "'" +"/>";
            var otuputString = imgSrc.concat(finalString); 

            return otuputString;

        }
        return dates;
    }
```

There is that little problem that no matter now many tabs I put in `var finalString = tempString.replace(/,/g," ,");` the space between the icons is always the same, no idea why. But that's the closest I get to what I've wanted.

Cheers

Leron

Comment: Can you post a screenshot what you finally will get with this approach? I have couple very similar places in my apps and it would be very interesting to compare our solutions.

Comment: Sha, glad to see you. Sorry for the delay but these weeks I can't work much from home, so I follow here only when I'm at work. I don't know how to upload image in a comment so you can see in my main post what I have achieved by now. If you have better results, please share because by now as yo will see it's not looking much pretty.

Comment: I actually like what you've got. I would probably try to put this detail information into a tooltip and present just part of it in the cell... But your look pretty good considering what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I would like to show just 1-2 dates and somehow show the others only when a certain row is selected but having in mind that all this is string I think grouping won't work, or at least I couldn't make it work. I'm looking right now at the example for `detail informtaion` but...dunno. Do you have any pretty idea how to construct grids like this where a certain column possess a large amount of info? I would like to keep the height of all rows equal but to provide easy access to all the info...Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you already looked at `Ext.us.PreviewPlugin` and `rowexpander` plugin?

Comment: Lol, no I haven't gonna do it right now :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. I'm gonna play with this a bit and probably that will be all for today so..glad to 'see; you and have a nice day. But in the end - you mentioned that you had to deal with this kind of issues several times, it would be great to post at least one pic, showin your solution of the problem :) Bye for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
'<img src ="file:///D:/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/img.png"/>'
```

Comment: You can't access 'D:\' like this, it should be 'file:///D:/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/img.png'.
Note1: Does this path really exist? 
Note2: On the internets, there is no drive called D, so this will work on your computer only.

Comment: @Leron: what do you get as hhh, what is its value? Maybe the problem lies somewhere earlier, in getting the ggg?

Comment: There is also an extra space between src and the equal-sign, which could cause unwanted results too.

Comment: Igor F. sorry for the slow answer, see in my main post what `hhh` returns. And would be very grateful if you can help me using local files.

Comment: @Leron, concerning tabs: They are ignored in HTML. To get a really clean layout, you'll need to put your data in TABLEs or DIVs with associated styles (CSS). A simpler, quick'n'dirty approach would be to insert &nbsp; (non-breaking spaces) instead of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space before your filename, also your filename isn't in quotes.